# Como convertir una llamada asíncrona en sincrona kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Estoy haciendo una app android con firebase al ejecutar este método mi objetivo es poder retornar el resultado de agregar una nueva persona, pero lo que ocurre es que como el método setValue de FirebaseDatabase es asincrono el metodo devuelve null antes de que la llamada asincrona pueda proporcionar un resultado en addOnCompleteListener si es satisfactorio, o en addOnFailureListener si fallo, lo que necesito es pausar el hilo para que no llegue al return vacio del metodo , si no que espere a ser notificado por el resutado de firebase

```
override fun addEmpty(person: Person?):Result {
            database.child(person!!.id!!).child("Email")

              .setValue(person.email)

              .addOnCompleteListener({
                        return it
                    })

              .addOnFailureListener({
                        return it
                    })
        return
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es esta ,tomada del vídeo 6 de Gaston sailen, esto es especialmente útil si estas usando clean arquitecture para evitar usar publisher/suscriber y añadir simplicidad al código y apegarte a la arquitectura limpia, para poder usar el método  Task.await() 
debes implementar esta librería 
    implementation('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.1.1')
en el gradle esta lo que hace es suspender la courotine hasta que la tarea sea completada.

```
    override suspend fun addEmpty(person: Person?): Result {
        var taskAsynch = database
                .child(person!!.id!!)
                .child("Email")
                .setValue(person.email)

        taskAsynch.await()

        if (taskAsynch.isSuccessful) {
            return taskAsynch.result
        } else {
            return taskAsynch.exception
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

hace un tiempo hice un par de videos sobre como hacerlo "sincrono" a este proceso, la ide aes usar una libreria que es de google-play-services-coroutines, y la idea es hacer tus metodos suspend para trabajar en corutinas y usar .await() en cada funcion que retorne un Task de firebase

Chequea los siguientes videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h0Czo52_fs&t

Segui esos videos (lo que buscas esta en el 16:30 y lo explico en los proximos videos)

Comment: No sería mejor agregar el procedimiento aquí? Así la respuesta se enriquece y la información se preserva

Comment: El procedimiento es muy largo, hay que desde implementar una libreria, usar corutinas, explicar corutinas y armar la arquitectura, lo mejor es que siga esos videos para tener un buen contexto de como funciona, ahi se explica paso a paso

Comment: Como te han comentado, la solución de convertir el callback a suspend es muy buena, hay un codelab de Google que lo explica. Otra opción es que el método no devuelva nada, pero se invoca una lambda que se pasa por parámetro(Result)->Unit. Y otra opción más, dependiendo de si estás usando aqui LiveData, pues no devolver nada pero actualizando su valor cuando sea success o failure.

Comment: Aun estoy mirando los videos Gastón Saillén  de verdad que no tuve tiempo de verlos antes, pero si estoy tratando de implementar clean arquitectura y no encontraba la forma de no contaminar la capa de dominio con la de framework sin utilizar el patron publiher/suscriber

Comment: Si te sirvió podés marcar la respuesta como correcta, un saludo